# having multiples clasess in a module in a package in Python?

Tags: python, class, module, directory, package

I'm having trouble understanding packages in Python. In particular, is it possible to have multiple classes in a module in a package in Python. For example:

```
Kitchen/            Top-level package
    __init__.py     Initialize the package kitchen
    Fridge.py       module Fridge.py
        Food        This is a class in module Fridge
        Temperature This is another class in module Fridge
    Recipe.py
        BeefStake   This is a class in module Recipe.py
```

In the `__init__.py`, the code will be:

```
from Fridge import Food, Temperature
from Recipe import BeefStake
__all__ = ['Fridge', 'Recipe']
```

Then I would create an instance of the Temperature class by

```
from Kitchen import *
f = Food()
T = Temperature()
```

I tried this, and only making `f = Food()` works. The other one showed up an error, something like `NameError: name 'Temperature' is not defined`

If anyone knows if it is possible to have 2 classes like this in a module in a package in Python. If so, what could be the problem in this approach?

Comment: The code you gave us does not demonstrate the problem you asked about, because `f = Food()` does _not_ work. Please give us either your real code, or, better, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), not just code that's sort of similar to your real code. It's impossible to debug what we can't see, when there are a million things you could have gotten wrong and no way of knowing which one you did.

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed us won't work for *either* `Food` or `Temperature`. You explicitly put this in `Kitchen`:

```
__all__ = ['Fridge', 'Recipe']
```

This means that, even though you've imported `Food` and `Temperature` into `Kitchen`, you don't re-export them. So, `f = Food()` will raise a `NameError`.

If you change this to, say:

```
__all__ = ['Food', 'Temperature']
```

Now everything works fine.

My guess is that in your real code, you made one of two mistakes:

- Forgot to include `Temperature` in `__all__`, just as you did with both `Food` and `Temperature` here, or
- Had a typo somewhere, e.g., `t = temperature()` with a lowercase `t`.

Normally I'd suspect that the first is more likely… but given that  you're inconsistent with capitalization, and misspelled `BeefSteak`, I'd check the second here.

Answer (score 0):

yes,you can have more than 1 class in a module in python